# Remover todas as tags dentro de um contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

Quero impedir a formatação de texto de em um site e para isso preciso remover todas as tags (exceto `<br>`) que tivessem dentro de uma caixa de texto, caso alguma pessoa pense em colar algum conteúdo de algum outro site.

Um exemplo para não ficar confuso:

```
var text = "<b>Olá</b>, Usuário<br><i>Seja bem vindo</i>!"
removeHTML(text) = "Olá, Usuário<br>Seja bem vindo!"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução é o uso de uma expressão regular para remover todas as tags de HTML excepto o `<br>` ou `<br/>`:

```js
var texto = "<b>Olá</b>, Usuário<br><i>Seja bem vindo</i>!";

texto = texto.replace(/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, '');

alert(texto); // Saída: Olá, Usuário<br>Seja bem vindo!
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira é:

1- partir isso pelas quebras de linha, ficando com uma array de pedacos de texto
2- depois criar um elemento novo e dar a esse elemento novo como HTML cada string
3- usar o innerText desse elemento pois assim o Browser faz o trabalho por nós :)
4- voltar a juntar a array repondo o separador

Podias fazer isso com RegEx mas o Browser é melhor que qualquer RegEx a saber o que são tags de HTML. Daí a minha sugestão de usar um elemento (via Browser).

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9rj59ocs/

```js
var text = "<b>Olá</b>, Usuário<br><i>Seja bem vindo</i>!"

function removeHTML(str) {
    var partes = str.split(/<br\s?\/?>/);
    return partes.map(function (str) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = str;
        return el.innerText;
    }).join('<br />');
   }

alert(removeHTML(text));
```

Comment: **Obrigado!** Nunca que eu ia pensar em usar innerText para isso rsrs

Comment: eita, tinha esquecido da tag <br/> que pode ser usada também, mas acho que consigo alterar seu código.

Comment: @IagoBruno editei a resposta para ser mais abrangente na tag `<br />`